# Обновление полей двух таблиц

Tags: mysql

Как можно, и можно ли вообще, осуществить обновление полей двух таблиц?

```
UPDATE workers INNER JOIN reviews_of_workers
ON workers.id = reviews_of_workers.worker_id

SET
@competence_rand = 7+FLOOR(RAND()*4),
@speed_work_rand = 7+FLOOR(RAND()*4), 

`reviews_total` = 1,
`competence_total` = @competence_rand,
`speed_work_total` = @speed_work_rand, 

`competence` = @competence_rand,
`speed_work` = @speed_work_rand

WHERE `workers`.`id`>=64508716;
```

Проблема в том, что не работает блок:

```
        @competence_rand = 7+FLOOR(RAND()*4),
        @speed_work_rand = 7+FLOOR(RAND()*4),
```

Если его поставить перед `UPDATE`, то работает, но вычисляется один раз и для всех строк.

Как можно сделать так, чтобы значения вычислялись каждый раз для каждой строки `UPDATE`? Может как-то при помощи хранимой процедуры?

Comment: `... competence_total = (@competence_rand := 7+FLOOR(RAND()*4)), `competence` = @competence_rand`

Comment: Спасибо, огромное, добрый человек!

Comment: @Руслан Лучшее "спасибо", отметить ответ как принятый.

Comment: @0xdb Не спорю, но комментарий нельзя отметить, как принятый ответ. Или можно?

Comment: @Руслан Вы уже отметили **ответ**, это достаточно. Про комментарий я и не упомянал.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В фразе set любая часть должна содержать обновляемую колонку, поэтому отдельные приравнивания, не меняющие никакую колонку не допустимы. Но можно совместить обновление колонки с запоминанием значения в переменной:

```
competence_total = (@competence_rand := 7+FLOOR(RAND()*4)),
competence = @competence_rand
```